# Error en variables de sesión PHP usando servidor smarterasp

Tags: php, variables, servidor, session

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<?php session_start();
    session_destroy();
    require_once("views/vista_index.php");
?>
```

Todo funciona bien en local pero al subir en este servidor de Smarterasp me da el siguiente error

```
Warning: session_start(): open(h:\php\sessiondata\sess_emmr4dq5vh8nkqojj20nn97gs2, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in H:\root\home\castillomanu-001\www\demobingoapp\index.php on line 1
```

Soy nuevo usando este tipo de servidores y no entiendo a que se debe este problema. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: parece que te busca la session dentro de h:\php\sessiondata. Ese directorio existe y puedes acceder a el? (no se como va los permisos en windows)

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, agregue session_save_path(); al inicio y funciono

```
    <?php session_save_path();
    session_start();
        session_destroy();
        require_once("views/vista_index.php");
    ?>
```